# Call Speech Server

Tags: iis

I want to call an IIS Server (MS SPeech Server).
The Speech Server is in our intranet.

I would prefere to call it from a mobilphone or something like this - but to simulate the call with a sipphone like phonerlite would be okay too. But i don't know how to connect the sipphone with the server ...

can somebody help me? :>

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used phonerlite, you have to use the TCP connection, and call the port 5060. On the speech Server you have to add the SIP Peers and the add it to "trusted Peers".